# UIWebView. Replace css properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, uiwebview, replace

The code look likes the following:

```
<style type=\"text/css\">
html{background: #000; margin: 0; padding: 0}
body {padding: 30px; background: #000;width: 85;margin:0 auto;color: #000;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;line-height: 1.3em;}
</style>
```

what to do if I want to replace for example html.background?

Usual NSString replacement is not suitable because there are could be a lot of similar properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the jQuery framework for this.

More information on CSS for jQuery is available here: http://api.jquery.com/css/